# Difference between HorizontalPodAutoscaler and GKE Cluster Autoscaler

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I can automatically provision nodes in response to increased load either via [Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler), which I can create a cluster with:

```
gcloud container clusters create example-cluster \
  --num-nodes 1 \
  --zone us-central1-a \
  --node-locations us-central1-a,us-central1-b,us-central1-f \
  --enable-autoscaling --min-nodes 1 --max-nodes 4
```

[Or via Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/horizontalpodautoscaler), which I can apply to an existing cluster with:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment <deployment-name> --min=1 --max=4
```

**What is the difference between Cluster Autoscaler and Horizontal Pod Autoscaling?** They seem like alternate approaches to the same goal (having infrastructure adjust dynamically in response to greater resource needs). For example, both allow a minimum and maximum node count to be specified. Yet the documentation for each makes no reference to the other.

Comment: See [How does Horizontal Pod Autoscaler worki with Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work-with-cluster-autoscaler). HPA scales replicas. Cluster Autoscaler scales nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Horizontal Pod autoscaler**: Allow to update the numbers of replicas of a targeted deployment. Based on a metric you specify (eg: CPU...). This only affect the numbers of pods (not the numbers of nodes).

**Cluster autoscaler**: Allow to add new nodes to a nodepool if pods are not schedulables due to a lack a ressources (eg: CPU, memory...). This only affect the numbers of nodes (not the numbers of pods).

(Note that you can use both at the same Time)